Centering multi-page, long table in landscape pages
I am trying to vertically center a multi-page, long table (with some cells having long text) in the landscape mode. I use xltabular and threeparttablex to make this table. Although the table can be successfully generated (kindly find below the MWE), it does not appear vertically centered on the pages (screenshots attached).
I have tried \centering, \begin{center}, \vfill, and \vspace*{\fill}, as mentioned in other posts, but obviously none of these works for this purpose. I would be very grateful for any advice or solutions to this problem.
Here is the MWE:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{xltabular,threeparttablex}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}

\begin{ThreePartTable}

    \begin{TableNotes}
        $^*$ \lipsum[1]
    \end{TableNotes}
    
    \begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{p{2cm}XX}
 
        \caption{TableName.} \\ 
        \toprule
        Column1 & Column2 & Column3  \\ \midrule
        \endfirsthead

        \multicolumn{3}{c}{Table \thetable~({\it continued})} \\[1pt]
        \toprule
        Column1 & Column2 & Column3  \\ \midrule
        \endhead
        
        \bottomrule
        \multicolumn{6}{r}{\footnotesize ({\it continued on next page})}
        \endfoot

        \bottomrule
        \insertTableNotes
        \endlastfoot
        
        Row1 & \lipsum[1] & \lipsum[1] \\
        Row2 & \lipsum[2] & \lipsum[2] \\
        Row3 & \lipsum[3] & \lipsum[3] \\
        Row4 & \lipsum[4] & \lipsum[4] 

    \end{xltabular} 

\end{ThreePartTable}

\end{landscape}

\end{document}

Here are the images showing the table is not in the center of the pages:



Welcome! Do you not get an error from this code?

If I correct your code so it compiles, I don't see anything wrong with the positioning, though the rules and headers don't behave as I'd wish. What am I looking at exactly?

Note that xltabular uses tabularx internally and tabularx's documentation says: don't use \multicolumn to cross any X column. So your use of \multicolumn here may cause trouble. I don't know whether xltabular is compatible with threeparttablex ....

I find that I have to change $^*$ \lipsum[1] to $\item[*] and \multicolumn{6}{r}{\footnotesize ({\it continued on next page})} to \multicolumn{3}{r}{\footnotesize (\textit{continued on next page})} in order to make your code compile without errors.

You wrote, "[the table] does not appear vertically centered on the pages". AFAICT, there's no expectation that the parts of an xltabular environment (from the second page onwards) should be vertically centered. What you're encountering is that if (logical) table rows contain many rows of text, the resulting page breaks can be rather unfortunate-looking. In my view, the real typographical remedy of this problem is not to impose vertical centering on the page; instead, it is to redesign the table so that there are fewer rows of text per (logical) row.

@cfr and Mico - Thanks for pointing out the error! I did see the error, but I guess Overleaf (which I was using) ignored it and compiled the file anyway; plus, the file looked fine except for the positioning of the table.

@Mico - Many thanks for fixing the code and sharing your insights! I followed your codes (except I used \item[*] rather than $\item[*] if I am not wrong); this generated another issue (which I guess is what cfr was mentioning about): the bottom rule disappears on page 2 and so does the header on page 3. (Despite this in the MWE, I don't have this issue in my own tex file; so it may be fine.)

@Mico - And you are totally right—it would be better to redesign the table since this is mainly a page break issue due to the long text. Nevertheless, I may have to live with it since this table already went through several iterations of refining (and some other users may face the same issue as well). You mentioned that "AFAICT, there's no expectation that the parts of an xltabular environment (from the second page onwards) should be vertically centered."; then, would we be able to (at the least) ensure to vertically center the table on page 1? Many thanks!

@tabiety - Please see the answer I just posted.

A document is never 'fine' if there's an error. After an error, the result is known to be unreliable, so you should never ignore these. Any output is only good for debugging. Unfortunately, Overleaf tends to obscure this and always tries to produce a PDF regardless of errors.

@cfr Thank you for your kind comment and pointing this out! I totally agree! There are always people (including me) who want to move fast while ignoring the fundamental things and best practices!

I believe best practice is not ignoring the bad boxes either, but I tend to settle for moderately decent practice ;).

Since vertical centering of the table fragments appears to be of paramount importance, you may need to give up on producing the table on the basis of a single xltabular environment. Instead, you may want to look into employing the rotating package and its sidewaystable environment -- one sidewaystable environment per page, and one tabularx environment per sidewaystable environment. Presumably, you'll want just one tablenotes environment for all three (?) tables; if so, you'll probably want to place this tablennotes environment on the final page.
And, do look into employing the caption package and its \ContinuedFloat directive to generate a common table number across all sidewaystable environments.
Hopefully, the following screenshots demonstrate that all the three table fragments are centered vertically within a page.





\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{tabularx} % for 'tabularx' env. and 'X' col. type
\usepackage{ragged2e} % for '\RaggedRight' macro
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X} % suppress full justification
\usepackage{rotating} % for 'sidewaystable' environment
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}  % for '\ContinuedFloat' macro
\usepackage{lipsum}   % for filler text

\begin{document}

% first page
\begin{sidewaystable}
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{TableName.}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} p{2cm} LL @{}}
\toprule
Column1 & Column2 & Column3  \\ 
\midrule
Row1 & \lipsum[1]\tnote{**} & \lipsum[1] \\
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\multicolumn{3}{r@{}}{\footnotesize(continued on next page)}
\end{tabularx}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{sidewaystable}

% second page
\begin{sidewaystable}
\begin{threeparttable}
\ContinuedFloat
\caption{TableName, part 2 of 3.}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} p{2cm} LL @{}}
\toprule
Column1 & Column2 & Column3  \\ 
\midrule
Row2 & \lipsum[2]\tnote{$\dagger$} & \lipsum[2] \\
\addlinespace
Row3 & \lipsum[3] & \lipsum[3]\tnote{$\ddagger$} \\
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\multicolumn{3}{r@{}}{\footnotesize(continued on next page)}
\end{tabularx}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{sidewaystable}

% third page
\begin{sidewaystable}
\begin{threeparttable}
\ContinuedFloat
\caption{TableName, part 3 of 3.}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} p{2cm} LL @{}}
\toprule
Column1 & Column2 & Column3  \\ 
\midrule
Row4 & \lipsum[4]\tnote{\S} & \lipsum[4] \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\bigskip
\footnotesize
\RaggedRight
\begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]
\item[**]         \lipsum[1][1-10] 
\smallskip
\item[$\dagger$]  \lipsum[2][1-10]
\smallskip
\item[$\ddagger$] \lipsum[3][1-10]
\smallskip
\item[\S]         \lipsum[4][1-10]
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}

\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}


Addendum to address the OP's follow-up question, about not only typesetting the tables in landscape mode but also having the pdf viewer display the pages in landscape mode.
The sidewaystable method places its contents in landscape mode. However, as you've discovered, it doesn't also instruct the pdf viewer to change the on-screen display of the landscape-mode table from portrait to landscape mode.
If that's an effect you wish to achieve, I suggest you proceed as follows. First, in the preamble, change \usepackage{rotating} to \usepackage{pdflscape}. Second, change all three instances of \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth} to `\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}. Third, change the overall layout from
% first page
\begin{sidewaystable}
...
\end{sidewaystable}

% second page
\begin{sidewaystable}
...
\end{sidewaystable}

% third page
\begin{sidewaystable}
...
\end{sidewaystable}

to
\begin{landscape}
% first page
\begin{table}[p]
...
\end{table}

% second page
\begin{table}[p]
...
\end{table}

% third page
\begin{table}[p]
...
\end{table}
\end{landscape}

Put differently, you will need to change the overall layout from using 3 sidewaystable environments to using 3 table[p] environments, encased in a single landscape environment.

Many thanks! This is a very COOOOOOL solution and absolutely a lifesaver! Just a quick question: how did you generate rotated pages with your code (or generally with the use of sidewaystable)?

For anyone who is interested in removing the colon from the table name in the \ContinuedFloat environment for more flexibility, this one-liner would help: \captionsetup[ContinuedFloat]{labelsep=space}

@tabiety - The sidewaystable environment rotates its contents 90 degrees and thus typesets its contents in landscape mode.

yes, using your code, the table itself displays in landscape mode while the pages in the PDF output are in portrait mode. However, in the images you showed, the pages in the PDF output are in the landscape mode, which raised my question. I know the landscape environment can do the job but obviously we have been trying to switch to sidewaystable (which I believe cannot directly give landscape PDF pages).

@tabiety - Thanks for clarifying your follow-up question about landscape vs portrait mode. Please see the addendum I posted below my initial answer. (For that initial answer, I did rotate the pages before creating the screenshots.)

Work perfectly! Many thanks!
